# fedora dual boot on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, fedora, multi-boot

I have a desktop with Windows 7 installed. Now, I want to install Fedora 14 along with Windows 7 as dual boot.

My desktop has one hard drive 320GB with  partition (local C:, recovery D: and HP_tools E:), these all I got when I bought my PC.

I have Fedora 14 DVD and partition wizard software. can anyone tell me how can I create partition to install fedora successfully.

Answer (score 2):

if you leave a free space in your disk (more than 5G) just boot the Fedora DVD and let it own partition software do the work for you. You just have to read and follow the instructions properly.

Answer (score 1):

you must specify how much the drive sizes.If your c drive contains more than 100gb.i prefer u need to split it.you have 2 choices,

1)You can use partition magic

2)reinstall windows7 and create a new partition by allocating about 30gb space for c drive

Comment: please mention your requirements.......

Answer (score 0):

in Windows 7, open the 'Start' menu, type "part" and something called "Partition Manager" or something will come up (it comes with Windows) and it'll show ur partitions that you already have, with the remaining memory labeled as a partition called 'free space'.  Create a new partition out of the free space, formatted in EXT4.  Install Ubuntu (very easy, the guide will show you how) on the partition and then afterwards Fedora has an option to install over a previous installation of linux (Ubuntu) and thats it.

---

### LifeHacker has a great guide for dual booting Windows 7 and Ubuntu: [LifeHacker Guide](http://lifehacker.com/5403100/dual+boot-windows-7-and-ubuntu-in-perfect-harmony)

since the guide shows you how to install Ubuntu next to Windows 7, and you can choose to install Fedora over Ubuntu, this guide, plus one one extra step is all you need.